# scrapy on Macbook error: Module 'tutorial' already exists

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

After installation of scrapy,
I use 'scrapy startproject tutorial' to start but it shows below:

```
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:tutorial iceless$ scrapy startproject tutorial
Error: Module 'tutorial' already exists
```

When I just type import scrapy, it shows:

```
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:~ iceless$ import scrapy
-bash: import: command not found
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:~ iceless$ scrapy.item
-bash: scrapy.item: command not found
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:~ iceless$ create scrapy.Item
-bash: create: command not found
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:~ iceless$ items.py
-bash: items.py: command not found
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:~ iceless$ cd tutorial
Icelesss-MacBook-Pro:tutorial iceless$ import scrapy
-bash: import: command not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the first error you listed, but for the second group, it looks like you're trying to run python commands in bash. To get into a python editor from the terminal, enter `$python` first. To run a python script from the terminal, try `$python my_script.py`

Comment: For the first block, if you're using Windows, you'll need to append Python to your PATH variable. If you're on Linux or MacOS, Python should already be in your PATH, but maybe try running `$which python` to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a relatively simple fix. It seems on some platforms that when installing `scrapy` a symlink does not get created or the cli tool does not get added to your `$PATH`. The first thing that needs to happen is finding the location of your current `Python` and version:

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python # your python location may be different

$ python -V
Python 3.6.5 # your version may be different (we need the first two digits)
```

Take the first two paths of the `which python` command and prepend it to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/scrapy
```

So you end up with:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/scrapy
```

Now the final step is to create an alias for the command in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias scrapy="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/scrapy"
```

> I've created a Bash script which should (hopefully) automate this
>   process:

**scrapy_alias.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(command -v python)
b=$(python -V | grep -oE "\\d\\.\\d")
c="${a%/bin*}/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/${b}/bin/scrapy"

printf "\\n# Scrapy alias\\nalias scrapy=\"${c}\"\\n" | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_profile
```

In terminal run the script, then source the changes to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ ./scrapy_alias.sh
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you should be able to start the tutorial:

```
$ scrapy startproject tutorial

New Scrapy project 'tutorial', using template directory '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/templates/project', created in:
    /Users/Username/Desktop/Scrapy_Tutorial

You can start your first spider with:
    cd tutorial
    scrapy genspider example example.com
```